# How to see a foreign key name in DB2 through command line

Tags: db2

I am facing problem to see the foreign key name.
In db2cc i can see from the table list with alter option. But i want to know how can we see from command line. To drop that foreign key.

Comment: If you don't specify what platform (zOS, iSeries, Linux/UNIX/Windows) and version of the database you're using, it's very difficult to help.

Answer (score 2):

select constname from SYSCAT.REFERENCES where TABNAME = '<your table>';

Answer (score 1):

```
select substr(tabschema,1,16) as tabschema, substr(tabname,1,16) as tabname, keyunique
  from syscat.tables
  where keyunique > 0
```

Comment: The above query is giving error. I replace the tabschema with inst user name and tabname with table name